# Why do I get this InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, scrutor

I've just upgraded my ASP.NET Core WebApi project from .NET Core **2.2** to **3.1**.

I've fixed up all of the compile-time errors, upgraded my Nuget packages, and I can now run the app.

However, When I call `Build()` on my `IHostBuilder`, I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate' while attempting to
>   activate 'MyProject.Api.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware'.

[image: InvalidOperationException]

The Middleware it's referring to is pretty standard.

### ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs

```
public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware> _logger;

    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // redacted
    }
}
```

The rest of my app initialisation is fairly standard and I didn't change much going from 2.2 to 3.1 (2.2 was working).

I did change from `services.AddMvc()` to `services.AddControllers()`.

### Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSerilog().UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
            {
                logging
                .AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                .AddConsole()
                .AddDebug();
            });
    }
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs` is being called and runs fine, but `Configure()` **never runs**. The `Build()` method always kills the app before it gets to `Configure()`.

My Startup's `Configure` method signature looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

Comment: Could you share your Startup.cs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this problem contains two main elements:

1. .NET Core 3.0 introduced a change regarding **service provider validation**.
2. My code is **registering too many classes**, causing the validation to fail.

The solution to my problem was to introduce the following code in `Program.cs`:

```
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider(opt =>
        {
            // this overrides the default service provider options
            // so that it doesn't validate the service collection (which raises exceptions)
        })
        [ ... ]
}
```

Thanks to other answers that directed my attention to my `Startup.cs`.

### Full explanation

I use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) to scan assemblies and auto-register classes. Scrutor is **finding and registering my Middleware** classes such as `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`.

It was doing this in .NET Core 2.2 as well as 3.1. So why did it only break in Core 3.1?

Because .NET Core 3.0 introduced the [Generic Host](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Host.cs) as the new default way to build a host.

The code now contains a part to enable `ValidateOnBuild` by default under the development environment. This caused my ServiceProvider to validate on build. And it couldn't resolve `RequestDelegate` because I didn't register that.

```
.UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
{
    var isDevelopment = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
    options.ValidateScopes = isDevelopment;
    options.ValidateOnBuild = isDevelopment;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is  the answer for those who use .netCore 6 :

- First Remove Property of **RequestDelegate** :

```
 private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
```

- And then remove Your Constructor for **RequestDelegate** :

```
public SomeClassName (RequestDelegate next)
{
   _next = next;
}
```

- finally , here is the Invoke method :

```
 public class SomeMiddleware : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi I am Middleware in .net6");
            await next(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simply RequestDelegate next cannot be on constructor, but only on InvokeAsync because is passed by framework

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem today and resolved it as follows:

In .net core 2.2 I added the middleware to the application builder and also added the middleware to the service collection. Apparently adding the middleware to the service collection is no longer required and results in the exception you posted.

In my case removing the line

```
services.AddSingleton<MyMiddleware>();
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As @user1796440 said,I could reproduce your issue by using `services.AddSingleton<MyMiddleware>();`.

To fix it,you need register middleware like below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    //...
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem is that my `Configure()` method is never called. The exception is thrown earlier, so I would never get to this point of `UseMiddleware()`.

Comment: So could you share your Startup.cs?It would be more helpful to resolve your issue.